# MatLab Graphing in GUIDE

Tags: graph, plot, matlab-guide

I am trying to graph the content of the arrays (one representing the coordinate in Y and the other the X values corresponding to these Y's)

Below is an image of the result I get:

[image]

Whereas I am trying to plot with a line connecting every point.

I am not sure how to do that.

Everything happends within a GUIDE gui.

Here is the code that generates the graph:

```
plot(handles.axes_pressure,handles.ArrayPosition,handles.PressureArray);
plot(handles.axes_capacitance,handles.ArrayPosition,handles.CapacitanceArray);
```

Time and position are interchageable here.
The ArrayPosition array contains the Y or position of eachpoint and the other two, respectively contain the pressure and capacitance measured at these positions.

Comment: What are the dimensions of ArrayPosition, PressureArray and CapacitanceArray?

Comment: They should all be 1D